# Is there a minimum output current for voltage regulators?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I need both 4.5V and 3.3V for a project, and my idea was to power it using a single battery and a voltage regulator. [A regulator I found](https://www.elfa.se/elfa3~se_sv/elfa/init.do?item=73-888-80&toc=19829) (MCP1700) has an output current of 200 mA, but I'm only going to pull 3-4 mA. Is that large difference a problem in any way? I couldn't find that information in the [data sheet](https://www1.elfa.se/data1/wwwroot/assets/datasheets/MCP1700_eng_tds.pdf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note this line in your datasheet:

[image]

There's no minimum load current, but if the load current is below 100 uA, there's no guarantee how well the regulator will be able to maintain the output voltage.