# Why is this 5V voltage regulator not outputting 5V?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I purchased a bunch of LM330T voltage regulators and in my testing, it's outputting about 5.9V when I feed it 6.5V.  It's listed as a 5V regulator at Digikey:

[LM330T-5.0/NOPB](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LM330T-5.0%2FNOPB/LM330T-5.0%2FNOPB-ND/32469?WT.srch=1&WT.medium=cpc&WT.mc_id=IQ62057685-VQ2-g-VQ6-40609413075-VQ15-1t1-VQ16-c)

Here's the data sheet: [LM330](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/National%20Semiconductor%20PDFs/LM330.pdf)

I must not be understanding something very fundamental here.  Can anyone explain?

Comment: Could you show us the circuit you are using? You're sure that the components aren't broken?

Comment: I have a very simple 4-AA battery pack connected to a breadboard. The positive from the pack is going to the input on the regulator. The ground on the pack is going to the ground on the regulator.  Then I have my meter probes connected to the output of the regulator and ground which is showing 5.89v.  Also, all of the regulators that I have are showing the same thing so it makes me feel like I'm just not understanding something.

Comment: Cap wire should be short and cap of the specified type, or else the circuit may be unstable

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/71374/is-there-a-minimum-output-current-for-voltage-regulators?rq=1

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have figured out which is the input pin, and which is output. The 6.5 to 5.9 drop sounds suspiciously like one diode drop, which some regulators exhibit when hooked up backwards. From the datasheet... with the legs pointing down, and the face with part number facing you, the input is on the left.

Comment: Yep - I have the input on the left and output on the right when it's facing me.  There's also a little dot on the bottom left (input side) that isn't shown in the diagram in the data sheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things:

- It sounds like you aren't using an output capacitor. Note the schematic on page 4 in the datasheet. "10 µF is the minimum value required for stability and may be increased without bound." Without this capacitor, the output is likely oscillating, which your meter might read as a funny voltage.
- It sounds like you have no load attached to the output. Load regulation is only specified for loads between 5 and 150 mA. Below 5 mA, the output voltage is likely to increase, at least slightly.

Comment: You're right, I don't have any capacitors or a load on it.  I'll add these, give it a load, and see if it helps. Thank you!

Comment: I added a 4uF cap on the input and a 10uF cap on the output and the voltage dropped to 4.89v which is much closer to the expected 5v.  I then applied a small 20 mA load and the voltage remains at 4.89v.  Shouldn't this be closer to 5v or is this typical?

Comment: It seems okay --- The spec is 4.75 to 5.25. If you need tighter tolerance, there's lots of regulators with better specs. They just cost slightly more than an LM330. You might have cooked your parts a little bit if you ran them a long time while oscillating. If you try a fresh one you might get better than +/- 0.1 V.